# Android image slider text change

Tags: java, android

I have used [this](http://javapapers.com/android/android-image-slider-tutorial/) for android image swipe. It's working fine. But I need some customization in it. I need text and button bellow image and text should be change according to image swipe. And the text and button should not swipe.

What I did i put two text view and button on fragment_page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:weightSum="1">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="217dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.71">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<TextView
    style="@style/bigFont"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textBold"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView
    style="@style/smallFont"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/textsmall"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textBold"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="REGISTER NOW"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:background="@drawable/button_design"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
    android:padding="@dimen/abc_action_bar_content_inset_material"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textsmall"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

here is my class.

```
package com.example.rocku28.mdt;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Slider extends FragmentActivity {
static final int NUM_ITEMS = 4;
ImageFragmentPagerAdapter imageFragmentPagerAdapter;
ViewPager viewPager;
TextView boldTxt,smallTxt;
Button regButton;

public static final String[] IMAGE_NAME = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);
    boldTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textBold);
    smallTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textsmall);
    imageFragmentPagerAdapter = new       ImageFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(imageFragmentPagerAdapter);

}


public static class ImageFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public ImageFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        SwipeFragment fragment = new SwipeFragment();
        return SwipeFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
}

public static class SwipeFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View swipeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_fragment, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) swipeView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        int position = bundle.getInt("position");
        String imageFileName = IMAGE_NAME[position];
        int imgResId = getResources().getIdentifier(imageFileName, "drawable", "com.example.rocku28.mdt");
        imageView.setImageResource(imgResId);
        setText(position);
        return swipeView;
    }
    public void setText(int position){
        // here I tried to change text on text view
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                new Slider().boldTxt.setText(R.string.verify_licence);
                new Slider().smallTxt.setText(R.string.take_back_picture);
                break;
            case 1:
              //  boldTxt.setText(R.string.verify_licence);
               // smallTxt.setText(R.string.take_front_picture);
                break;
            case 2:
              //  boldTxt.setText(R.string.dashboard);
               // smallTxt.setText(R.string.choose_option_to_call);
                break;
            case 3:
               // boldTxt.setText(R.string.helpline);
              //  smallTxt.setText(R.string.call_call_center);
                break;
        }
    }

    static SwipeFragment newInstance(int position) {
        SwipeFragment swipeFragment = new SwipeFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("position", position);
        swipeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return swipeFragment;
    }


}
```

}

check settext method. Here I tried to change text but problem is this context is in another class and it's static so I couldn't able to change it. How could I make it working?

Comment: You can user onPageListner of view pager and by getCurrentItem you change your text view

Comment: Can you please explain it? Because I'm still not getting. as you mentioned, implements listener. Can you please provide some code so I can understand properly.

Comment: Cheers.. Enjoy coding...!

Comment: Hi @RahulPatel how did u fixed? because I'm facing with the same issue, but the problem is that getItem() called twice and happens that jump from textview0 to textview2 without showing textview1.. could you help me please... Here is the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35466230/viewpager-activity-change-content-when-slide/35467055#35467055